# Does mysqldump return a status?

Tags: mysql, shell-scripting

I am creating a script that backups a mysql db using the mysqldump utility. I am writing this script in the shell "sh". I would like to capture the output status of mysqldump in the script (i.e. if the mysqldump command failed or succeeded) so I can report if the script was successful or not.

- Does mysqldump return an output
  status?
- Can someone please give me instructions on how to do this?

Comment: You could just check that the file was created and the last line contains something like `-- Dump completed on ...` - If there was a problem then this won't be the case.

Comment: I am creating dump through shell script so i want to get the idea dump is properly created or not through some status.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

mysqldump returns

```
0 for Success
1 for Warning
2 for Not Found
```

It also prints an extended error message to stderr e.g.

`mysqldump: Got error: 1049: Unknown database 'dbname' when selecting the database`

You can inspect the returned value like so

```
mysqldump -u DBuser -pDBpassword database >database.sql 2>database.err 
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Mysqldump encountered a problem look in database.err for information"
fi
```

Comment: i am not able to return the Success of Failure error message to my email ? Please help sir...

Comment: Curious issue in 2020, either MySQL 5 or 8 emits some an exit code. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90538

Answer (score 3):

After dump finished check $? shell variable. If it's 0 - all went fine. Else - error.

```
# mysqldump -u aaa -d msf>/dev/null
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'aaa'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
# echo $?
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Warn for people reading this question: Sometimes mysqldump gives exit code 0 even if it has error.

For example, this is what I see today:

```
I have no name!@backup-mysql-manual-20hvd-pp6m2:/$     mysqldump       --host="${MYSQL_HOST}"       --port="${MYSQL_PORT}"       --user="${MYSQL_USER}"       --password="${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"       --all-databases > /tmp/a.sql 
mysqldump: Error: 'Access denied; you need (at least one of) the PROCESS privilege(s) for this operation' when trying to dump tablespaces
I have no name!@backup-mysql-manual-20hvd-pp6m2:/$ echo $?
0
```